# Parameter pack not expanded when moving code out of class definition

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17, fold

I have template class which looks like this:

```
template<typename... Args>
class Foo
{
public:
    void Bar() {
        (std::get<Args>(m_args).Bar(), ...);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<Args...> m_args;
};
```

And here is how I am using it:

```
template<size_t I>
class Test
{
public:
    void Bar() {
        std::cout << I << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo<Test<0>, Test<1>> object;
    object.Bar();
}
```

This version works just fine, but I need to move method definition out of class interface (to increase it's readability). The question is what the syntax to do that trick?

I've tried this:

```
template<typename... Args>
void Foo<Args...>::Bar() {
    (std::get<Args>(m_args).Bar(), ...);
}
```

but compilation fails with error message:

```
error C3520: 'Args': parameter pack must be expanded in this context
note: while compiling class template member function 'void Foo<Test<0>,Test<1>>::Bar(void)'
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void Foo<Test<0>,Test<1>>::Bar(void)' being compiled
note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Foo<Test<0>,Test<1>>' being compiled
error C2228: left of '.Bar' must have class/struct/union
error C2059: syntax error: '...'
```

I have checked this code on clang 7 and it works so it looks like MSC compiler bug (visual studio 15.7.1).

[Bug at developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/250767/compile-error-while-splitting-template-class-metho.html)

Comment: Seems like an MSVC bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This thing looks like MSVC bug and reproduces when using fold expressions.
So the workaround is downgrade code from C++ 17 to C++ 14 and use 'classic' `initializer_list` hack:

```
template<typename... Args>
void Foo<Args...>::Bar() {
    (void)std::initializer_list<int>{
        (std::get<Args>(m_args).Bar(), 0)...
    };
}
```

Comment: Please file a bug report with Microsoft - and link to it from here, so other people can know when this is fixed.